# Неопределенный заголовок в списке модулей

Tags: opencart

Друзья, может кто сталкивался, подскажите, почему в админке, на странице модули/расширения, в фильтре где вы мы выбираем тип расширения, появился неизвестный заголовок, heading_title (0), откуда он взялся? как его убрать?[image: вот скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы тыцнули `Выделить все` в настройках Группы пользователя в секциях `Разрешен просмотр` и `Разрешено внесение изменений`. В результате в этих списках был, среди прочих, отмечен роут `extension/extension/promotion`. Это роут расширения, у которого нет ни пользовательских настроек, ни локализации (по этой причине там `heading_title` - переводов нет).

Этот модуль отвечает за показ рекламных банеров (их можно наблюдать в секции `Модули / Расширения`) и пользователем никак не управляется.

Это недоработка команды **Opencart**. Либо собирались расширить функционал расширения но зарелизили не дописав, либо провтыкали, либо тупо забили.

Найдите и анчекните `extension/extension/promotion` в `Разрешен просмотр` и `Разрешено внесение изменений` в `Система-Пользователи-Группы Пользователей-[группа]`

Comment: Спасибо большое за инструкцию!